# Gmail: Get a message body from within an extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I’m writing a Chrome extension for Gmail. I want to replace the default list view with a custom made one.

I want to fetch all message bodies for all displayed messages. How can I do so from within a Chrome extension?

Gmail has [ATOM feed of unread messages](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed). It doesn’t have a feed for all messages.

Gmail has a gmonkey object. [1.0 version is documented](http://code.google.com/p/gmail-greasemonkey/wiki/GmailGreasemonkey10API). There is also undocumented 2.0 version. None of them allow me to fetch a message body.

Gmail for iPad stores all messages in WebSQL storage. Unfortunately, desktop Gmail does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get any other answers, you can always do it the hard way, via [Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html), basically by injecting jQuery, scraping message bodies, readjusting DOM structures, etc.

Comment: ... or, better yet, contribute to gmonkey object and extend it. Also, checkout other extensions - there are tons of them for gmail. For example: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dheionainndbbpoacpnopgmnihkcmnkl/details?hl=en has an option to "Homogenize the appearance of incoming emails, i.e. same font/color/size" which probably requires access to email contents.